# Content Duplication when Extending CKAN with a custom theme

Tags: python, django, jinja2, ckan

Edit: Using CKAN 2.8.3 currently

So I am trying to extend CKAN using our theme and I keep encountering issues due to plugin order (I believe) and content duplication. For example in 2 instances, I am trying to fix a missing font-awesome ICON in the Issues tab and rename Groups to Collections.

The template file is ckan/templates/package/read_base.html and I am trying to override in dmt_theme/templates/package/read_base.html

The following Screenshots and code output:

```
{% ckan_extends %}

{% block package_organization %}
{% endblock %}

{% block content_primary_nav %}
  {{ super() }}
  {% if h.issues_enabled(pkg) %}
    {{ h.build_nav_icon('issues_dataset', _('Issues'), dataset_id=pkg.name) }}
  {% endif %}
{% endblock %}
```

Produces this:
[image]

And when I try to copy the content from CKAN's read_base.html file to just rewrite and control the whole block of content...

[image]

[image]

And regardless of where I put the plugins in my development.ini file it seems to have the same effect. The plugin order is another issue I been battling for the better part of a year now.

Comment: Whick ckan version you are using?

Comment: CKAN 2.8.3 
I think the issue here is I am not actually overriding the extension template files themselves. 

ckanext/datastore/templates/package/resource_read.html for example to override the data dictionary columns... 
I am struggling trying to figure out how to do that

Same is holding true for the issues above, I do not believe I am actually hitting the extension template file, so it is being ignored. But I cannot figure out how to get the paths down correctly for those

Comment: Can you please try to extend the location in your extension as: ckanext-datastore/templates/package/resource_read.html ?

Comment: So the paths I currently have are: 
~/Projects/ckanext-dmt_theme/ckanext/dmt_theme/templates/package/resource_read.html

Which is my local and the ckan core path is:
~/Projects/ckan/ckanext/datastore/templates/package/resource_read.html 

Respectively. It seems the only way I can ever override this file is if it is first in my ckan.plugins = settings. Ill post that as well, because the plugin order has been the bane of my existence for the past year

Comment: ckan.plugins =  xloader resource_proxy discovery search_suggestions similar_datasets text_view image_view recline_view recline_grid_view recline_graph_view recline_map_view webpage_view pdf_view twitter_view stats dmt_theme datastore datarequests issues ldap